# Need to have date mask depending on the culture in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, culture

MVC pages with culture depending on the user. In Search option (search can be done by DueDate), I need to have a mask on that DueDate text box. Mask must be dependant on the user's culture. In both js and cshtml have an error saying: `mask.split is not a function`. Changed my `jquery.maskedinput-1.2.3.js` from `make.split` to `make.toString()`.split and the error is gone, but must looks like this: `[object Object]` or has some `01` numbers. Any idea? Code in `cshtml` looks like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var maskFormat = @Html.CurrentDateMask();
        $(".DateBox").mask(maskFormat);
    });
   </script>
```

Comment: what does `@Html.CurrentDateMask()` return? I think you want it as a string: `var maskFormat = "@Html.CurrentDateMask();";` to create a Javascript string.

Comment: it does return a string - and yes - it helps :) thank you very much :) Additional question to it - can this be done entirely in js - with no use of any outside helpers? I have a js common for different pages and instead of changing pages - I'd like to change that js...

Answer (score 1):

you could have maskFormat as a global variable (put it in the window object) and then refer it to window.maskFormat inside your JS file:

cshtml file:

```
(function () {
    window.maskFormat = "@Html.CurrentDateMask();";
})();
```

and in your Javascript file:

```
$(function(){
    $(".DateBox").mask(window.maskFormat);
});
```

but be careful so you don´t add to many global variables or with a name thats easy to overwrite